# Angular SEO: Google Webmaster Tools and Prerender.io on IIS

Tags: angularjs, seo, prerender

I'm using PreRender.io for MVC https://github.com/greengerong/Prerender_asp_mvc.

Everything works fine with facebook crawler. I can share my posts and facebook shows prerendered result.

I'm using pushState and in my head section I have included

I have issue with Google WebMaster Tool. When I'm trying to fetch my page it doesn't add "?_escaped_fragment_="  automatically to my link. When I will put manually "?_escaped_fragment_=" to the end of the link everything works perfect.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please help me in letting me know how you configured the IIS? I am trying to test it locally but get a blank page with `?_escaped_fragment_=`

Comment: To gave you an idea, this is what I am doing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051510/prerender-io-iis-configuration