# prerender.io IIS configuration

Tags: iis, seo, prerender

I am trying to implement Prerender.io in my ASP.NET application. I configured all the required necessary steps including

1)`<meta name="fragment" content="!">` in head of Index.html

2) Configured the Module

```
 <httpModules>
      <add name="Prerender" type="Prerender.io.PrerenderModule, IslamicMatchMakers.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
    </httpModules>
```

3) Added Custom Header

```
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Prerender-Token" value="XXXX" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

4) Defined Rewrite rules

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>

        <!--# Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML-->
        <rule name="Prerender" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent))(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="_escaped_fragment_" ignoreCase="false" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://service.prerender.io/http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Html5Mode" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="/scripts/" negate="true" />
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="/content/" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

5) I installed the Application Request Routing Module on IIS, in which I enable the Proxy. Here is the image how it looks like:
[ARR](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vetget88nnubyvi/ARR.PNG?dl=0)

Now after all these configuration when I make a request to http://localhost:2525?_escaped_fragment_=

It just show me a blank page. I am not sure what I am missing, can anyone please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't be able to see anything if you're running on localhost. The Prerender.io servers can only access publicly available websites, so you could try pushing your code to a public staging server...or download our open source server and run it locally to test things first.

Feel free to email me if you have any more questions about getting things up and running! :)

todd@prerender.io

Comment: I tried the same approach as OP said on live website. Still its not working. I get 'We haven't seen a request with your Prerender token yet' on prerender dashboard

Comment: Please send us an email at support@prerender.io with some more information and we'll be happy to help look into it!